# SSIS Packages transition to another machine

Tags: ssis

I have a couple of SSIS packages that resides on my local drive at work that run scheduled jobs. I will be leaving my current position in a couple off days, and would like to help my department transition smoothly.

My question is, for the person that will be picking up my duties, how can I transfer these dtsx packages to their computer short of recreating the packages from scratch on their local drive? If I'm not mistaken the SQL Agent runs off the user login account? After my last day my account will be deleted and none of the jobs will run.

Please provide some insight on what's the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: Does the SQL Agent that executes the packages also reside on your local pc? The SQL Agent executes the packages under it's service account, you can check which account this is with the `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Comment: Yes, everything resides on my local.

Comment: Are the SQL connections in the SSIS packages made with your SQL user account or with a "trusted connection" (i.e. windows credential of the current user)?

Comment: It's made with a trusted connection.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to stop running things locally. SSIS packages should be set up and run on the database server and should use server accounts that won't disappear when people leave. We have a separate account for dev, QA, and staging as well as prod as some of the other environments are onteh same server.

Comment: So in short there is no quick way around my current setup and I would have to recreate these packages from scratch on the server?

Comment: We save out SSIS packages as files and put them in source control, so we don't rebuild the package, just copy the file to the correct place.

Comment: My apologies if you have to dumb this down a little more for me, as I'm fairly new to SSIS. My SQL Server Integration Services projects are located in C:\ETL, can I copy these packages to the server, or the intended user local C and the package will still run after my account is deactivated?

Comment: Since you are using trusted connections, the database connections will be made with whatever credentials are running the package. Copy the files you have now to either the other developer's machine or a server and schedule them to run. If you get the permissions right on the database and the computer, they should run as is.

Comment: Bill, Thanks for replying, I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with HLGEM about best practice, you have a couple of "quick and dirty" options.

One really dirty way is to mess with the service account that the SQL Agent uses. Usually it runs as Local Service or Network Service, but you can make it run under domain credentials that have access to the appropriate data sources. Careful, this is a big security hole.

SQL Agent also has a mechanism for running particular job steps under different credentials. Look into "Credentials" and "Proxies". This setup is really valuable at the server level, but is a lot of extra work just to run a job from a developer's machine.

Finally, there is no reason that SQL Agent has to be involved at all. You can run a dtsx package from command line or from an SSIS repository under the current user's credentials. This works fine if you are running packages as needed. Not so good for scheduled runs.

Comment: The third option would not work for me, I have twenty five scheduled jobs that runs daily.